# Do all binaries built on VS2013 require msvcr120.dll/msvcp120.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msvcrt

I ported couple of VS 2005 projects to VS 2013.
Found that some of them require msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll while some of them are happy with msvcrt.dll. Why is that difference? I confirmed the dependencies through Dependency Walker.
Please note that none of my projects are using MFC so their project setting is Use Standard Windows Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The binaries that depend on msvcr120.dll/msvcp120.dll are those that are using the Visual Studio 2013 C/C++ libraries.

In order to depend on msvcrt.dll, you need to use the Windows Driver Kit as I believed that the regular Windows SDK doesn't allow app developers to depend on msvcrt.dll since this is a Windows component.